# HTML tag removing when export to excel

Tags: php, javascript, excel

I am using this script to export html table to excel file but I have image tag in table so I want to remove that tag when script export to excel. Here is the script I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var tableToExcel = (function() {
         var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
         return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
         }
       })()
       </script>

       <input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('datatable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
```

[image: Here is the snapshot of exported excel sheet. Due to all image tag it shows cross sign. I want to remove that images.]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `<img>` tags like this:

```
table: table.innerHTML.replace(/<\s*img[^>]*>/gi,'');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5cVrX/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
   window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#export').html()));
});
```