# Export to Excel from table or data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, export-to-excel

We have a requirement to export data in to excel from table, after export user will enter values in empty cell, that cell value will be added with another cell and it will display in the formula column.

For example:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Formula Column</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the above example after exporting, column 1 and column 2 value is empty for some rows. In the excel user will enter the values, after that the formula column should populate the sum.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672251/html-tag-removing-when-export-to-excel

Comment: Check this out for export to excel i dont know how to handle the formula part: https://codepen.io/kostas-krevatas/pen/mJyBwp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx), a JavaScript library to read and write spreadsheets.